# expression must have integral or unscoped enum type with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing this code to read a N integer array, then I suppose to check the even numbers and print them alone.

this is what I wrote,  but I get this error: 
expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int N;
    int count_even = 0, count_odd = 0;
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    float *arr = new float[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf_s("%f", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if (arr[j] % 2 == 1){
            count_odd++;
        }
    }
}
```

the error on this line: " if (arr [j]) % 2 ==1)

Comment: "even" and "odd" usually apply to integers, so why an array of floats?

Comment: It is a homework, I suppose to use array of floats

Comment: void main is illegal. You forget to delete your array. Why not use `vector<float>`

Comment: @RuaaBrkat: Does your homework also require you to use deprecated headers, non-standard library functions, a non-standard type for `main`, and leak-prone manual memory management, as well as a strange definition of "odd" and "even"? If so, you should drop the course before you waste any more time, and teach yourself C++ from [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: @Mike Seymour.. this is the homework: Q1: Write a program which reads an integer N from the user. The program then allocates a float array 
of size N and reads the array elements from the user. The program then copies the elements with odd 
indicies into a new array called Odd and the elements with even indices into a new arrays called Even. 
Finally the program prints the Odd and Even Arrays.

Comment: @RuaaBrkat: Read it more carefully. It says "odd indicies" (sic), not "odd values". Your test should be `j%2` not `arr[j]%2`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do `<float> % <int>`:

```
if (arr[j] % 2 == 1) {
//  ^^f^^^   ^i
```

There is no such operator. What you want to use instead is [fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod), defined in the `<cmath>` library.

Comment: Is there another way without using cmath library and fmod operator, we didn't study them in University yet..

Comment: @RuaaBrkat You could write that function yourself, it's not that complicated, just think about the definition of mod. Also, now that I think about it... what is an odd float anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have integer values, you could use `int` for `arr`:

```
int *arr = new int[N];
```